# 'Rent' a mathematician?

Tags: education

is it possible to 'rent' in a webpage or similar a mathematician ?

i mean, for example i am a physicist or a chemist and i must solve an equation or math problem

are there places to 'pay' a mathematician to do the calculations for you ? you pay him and he/she helps you with your equation or solve your equation

im not telling only about homework but suppose i have an equation i can not solve (because i am not intelligent) like $ u_{t}=U_{xxxx}+f(u,x,t) $

then i 'rent' someone to do the calculations for me ? does it exists? as a businnes or similar

Comment: How about contacting mathematicians at your local university?

Comment: they may refuse you if you don't pay them money, i know it by experience

Comment: Well, if those mathematicians aren't willing to do your work for free, you can try to enslave them...Anyway, you **will** pay, either by internet or with local ones, so why don't you approach local ones?

Comment: @JoseGarcia If your problem comes from you doing research, then you can pay the mathematician by including them in the final paper.

Comment: My experience: I was stuck with a problem for more than 10 years. Some month ago, I set a bounty for it on MathSE and apparently, someone solved it for me. Turned out it wasn't an easy problem and I would be stuck with it for the eternity...

Comment: i was telling this for example if some day i do a research for an University or if in my job (i am currently unemployed) i have to solve an equation but i do not know how to solve it ;)

Comment: Maybe in the next version of MSE you will be able to rent any high-reputation user with a fee that depends on his reputation :D